# set bits 1-3 in an int given an int with only bits 1-3 set as desired

Tags: java, c++, c, bit-manipulation, bit-fields

```
unsigned int x = 0xdeadbeef;
unsigned int y = 0x00000006;
unsigned int z = 0xdeadbee7;
```

How to compute the value in `z` from the values in `x` and `y`?

Bits 1-3 of `y` are `011` and I want bits 1-3 of the value in `x` to be replaced with bits 1-3 of `y` leaving the other bits as they are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you should:

- Mask off bits 1-3 so that they *can't* be set
- OR the result with bits 1-3 of y

So:

```
// 0xe == 8 + 4 + 2 (i.e. bits 1-3)
z = (x & ~0xe) | (y & 0xe);
```

Note that `~` is the bitwise *inverse* operator, so to clear 3 bits you take the inverse of those bits set, and use the bitwise AND of that inverse with the current value.

You can just use `| y` instead of `| (y & 0xe)` if you know that only bits 1-3 will be set in `y`.

(Note that I've assumed that by "bits 1-3" you mean the bits with value 8, 4 and 2, using the normal bit-counting mechanism of starting from 0. If you meant "the bottom three bits", that would normally be bits 0-2, and you'd use 7 instead of 0xe in the code.)

Comment: @necromancer: Goodo - I'll leave the bit clarification there for any future readers who were wondering.

Comment: actually, another thing that would be helpful would be how to best update the value of `x` instead of assigning to a new variable `z`